# Spring boot constructor based Runtime dependency injection

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application in which I want Employee objects to be injected by Spring. There are two methods in which I pass different arguments to Employee constructor to get different objects in method1 and method2. Like this I may have methodn in which I pass different arguments to constructor and get different Employee objects dynamically.How do I do it using Autowired annotation without using xml configuration

```
package com.test;


public class EmployeeCreation{

    public Employee method1(){
        Address add1 = new Address("street1", "street2");
        Employee e1 = new Employee("emp1", add1);
        return e1;
    }

    public Employee method2(){
        Address add2 = new Address("street3", "street4");
        Employee e2 = new Employee("emp2", add2);
        return e2;
    }

}



class Employee {

    private String name;
    private Address address;
    public Employee(String name, Address address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

}

class Address {
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    public Address(String street1, String street2) {
        this.street1 = street1;
        this.street2 = street2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration class, declare methods that return `Employee` and annotate them with `@Bean`. Then, in your `@Service` you can inject the beans using `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` where the qualifier name is the name of the configuration method used to define the bean.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{

    @Bean
    public Employee employee1(){
        Address add1 = new Address("street1", "street2");
        Employee e1 = new Employee("emp1", add1);
        return e1;   
    }
    @Bean
    public Employee employee2(){
        Address add2 = new Address("street2", "street3");
        Employee e2 = new Employee("emp2", add2);
        return e2;   
    }
}
```

Then, in your classes you can just use `@Autowired` to retrieve either `Employee`

```
public class EmployeeRetrieval{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("employee1")
private Employee emp1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("employee1")
private Employee emp1;

//your code here
}
```

Comment: What I want is Employee objects dynamically getting generated based on the constructor. In different methods I would pass different address as parameters to constructor. Arguments to constructors are dynamically generated and this should be passed to Employee constructor. What you suggested is static.

Comment: Can you explain a little what you mean by "dynamic"? Where is the employee information coming from?